How does React update only the parts of the DOM that need updating?
How is React able to update only the parts of the DOM that require updating (because they've changed) as opposed to re-rendering the entire DOM?
From what I understand, regular HTML/Javascript web pages react to changes in the DOM by re-rendering the entire DOM. I also understand that React uses a virtual DOM to determine what has changed and what has not. It compares the previous state of the virtual DOM with the new one to determine what has changed and updates the real DOM to match the virtual DOM only on the nodes that have changed. I also understand that when transpiled, React code is converted to regular Javascript.
Putting this all together leads to the question above. If React just becomes regular Javascript after transpilation, then at run time, it's the same situation as a regular HTML/Javascript web page. But this is said to render the entire DOM in response to any change in the DOM. So how does the code only update the parts of the DOM that need updating? The browser doesn't know (nor would it care) that it used to be React code, so why should it handle the DOM any differently than a regular HTML/Javascript web page? Is there a way in plain Javascript to tell it to update only part of the DOM instead of re-rendering the entire DOM? Is that what a React application is doing after being transpiled to plain Javascript?

When you do something like this:
<div>Hello World</div>

It gets transpiled to something like this:
import { jsx } from 'react/jsx-runtime';
// ...
jsx('div', { children: "Hello World" });

That jsx function returns a small object which looks roughly like this:
{
  type: 'div',
  key: null,
  props: {
    children: "Hello World"
  }
}

In more complicated examples the children property can be (and often is) another element, which could then have children of its own, and so on. So as your components render you are building up a bunch of these objects in a tree.
To figure out what has changed, react compares the tree from the previous render with the new tree. For a given element, react first looks at the type and key. If either one of those has changed, then this is a new element; it must be unmounted and a new one mounted in its place. If the type and key match, it next checks the props. If the props have changed, then it knows it needs to update that prop.
After that it repeats the comparison for the children of the element, then the children's children, etc. At the end it has built up a list of changes, and it then pushes those changes (if any) to the DOM, using built in browser functions like appendChild

This is strange. I read the link you provided for document.append. It says it throws an error if you try to append an extra root element (). Otherwise, it appends the node to the document as its last child. How is this used to update the DOM?

Oops, i meant appendChild. Anyway, react will use whatever dom methods it needs to to make the changes. appendChild is what it uses when it needs to insert a dom element. For other operations it will use other functions, but they're all ones that are native to the browser and the dom. You can poke around this file if you want to see some of the others react uses, but the file is admittedly hard to follow: https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/main/packages/react-dom-bindings/src/client/ReactFiberConfigDOM.js

I see... so I must be mistaken to assume that with regular javascript, the entire DOM is re-rendered for any change. I was under the impression that if you used methods like appendChild it would append a child to whatever element you call it on, but then it would go through the whole tree to re-render on the screen. This must be wrong. So then what's the problem React is trying to solve?

In a complicated app it can be difficult to know which parts of the DOM you need to manipulate to transform the page from what it looks like now to what you want it to look like. If you're writing manual code to alter the DOM, then you may resort to changing more parts than necessary, just because it's too hard to do it right. The sloppiest of code (but also the easiest) would be to rerender the entire DOM. React and other ui libraries handle the task of figuring out the minimum set of DOM changes, and then applying those for you.

In short: react makes it easy to do precision updates to the DOM. You can do that without react too, it's just not easy.

Ah, I see. Thanks for the clarification, Nicholas.

The Theory
DOM Manipulation, as you know, is an expensive process. The reflow, the repaint, executing the scripts, all of that takes a toll on the browser. React is efficient exactly for the optimized the diffing and the reconciliation algorithms.
React maintains a lightweight virtual DOM, which is nothing but just a JavaScript object. It compares the differences between the new VDOM and the current one every time it's required to re-render the component.
Think of it this way. What makes React re-render its components? Any changes in state variable or props values. So, React does not need to update the whole DOM tree. It updates only what is necessary. In other words, only the elements that are dependent on the props data or the state variable.



Now, it's not like after transpilation React turns into regular JavaScript; but rather, React itself is just a bunch of functions and algorithms written in JavaScript. It's the JSX codes that get transpiled into a React element (which is again just a JS object). So, when you write React code like setState or useState, React internally manages the state and invokes its algorithms to compute changes and re-render the component, allowing partial updates to the real DOM.
At runtime, the browser still executes this JavaScript logic, which includes React's diffing algorithm to figure out which DOM elements need to change. So, it’s not that the browser suddenly “knows” the code came from React; instead, it’s React’s efficient DOM manipulation logic embedded in the JavaScript code that ensures partial updates.



Let's implement it!
A skeleton HTML page that will be populated using JavaScript
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Imitating React</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="content"></button> <button id="element"></button>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>


Let's create a React-like functional component in plain JavaScript
<script>
  const btn = document.querySelector("#content");
  btn.textContent = "Change Content";
  btn.setAttribute("onClick", "changeElement(true)");

  const btn2 = document.querySelector("#element");
  btn2.textContent = "Change Element";
  btn2.setAttribute("onClick", "changeElement(false)");


  // React-like functional component
  const App = () => {
        const div = document.createElement('main');
        div.setAttribute("id", "main");
        const article = document.createElement("article");
        article.setAttribute("class", "post");
        article.setAttribute("id", `post-1`);

        const h2 = document.createElement("h2");
        h2.textContent = `Common Raven`;
        article.appendChild(h2);

        const p = document.createElement("p");
        p.textContent = `This is a bird.`;
        article.appendChild(p);

        div.appendChild(article);
        return div;
   };

  // rendering the App in root
  const root = document.getElementById("root");
  root.appendChild(App());
</script>

The React Diffing algorthim works in two ways. If the updated element in the new VDOM is of the same type, it only changes the content of the element. Else it replaces the old element with a new one.
<script>
 
  const changeElement = (isElementSameType) => {
        // Diffing Algorithm Running to determine the difference
        if(isElementSameType) 
          updateContent();
        else
          updateElement(); 
  };
</script>

Try it out yourself


const btn = document.querySelector("#content");
btn.textContent = "Change Content";
btn.setAttribute("onClick", "changeElement(true)");

const btn2 = document.querySelector("#element");
btn2.textContent = "Change Element";
btn2.setAttribute("onClick", "changeElement(false)");

// React-like functional component
const App = (elem) => {
  const div = document.createElement('main');
  div.setAttribute("id", "main");
  const article = document.createElement("article");
  article.setAttribute("class", "post");
  article.setAttribute("id", `post-1`);

  const h2 = document.createElement("h2");
  h2.textContent = `Common Raven`;
  article.appendChild(h2);

  const p = document.createElement("p");
  p.textContent = `This is a bird.`;
  article.appendChild(p);

  div.appendChild(article);

  return div;
};


const root = document.getElementById("root");
root.appendChild(App('div'));

const updateContent = () => {
  const Birds = [
    "American Robin",
    "Blue Jay",
    "Northern Cardinal",
    "Black-capped Chickadee",
    "House Sparrow",
    "European Starling",
    "American Goldfinch",
    "Downy Woodpecker",
    "Red-winged Blackbird",
    "Mourning Dove",
  ];

  document.getElementById("post-1").children[0].textContent =
    Birds[Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)];
};

const updateElement = () => {
  randomElements = [
    "h1",
    "h2",
    "h3",
    "p"
  ];
  child = document.getElementById("post-1").children[0];
  newChild = document.createElement(
    randomElements[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)]);
  newChild.textContent = child.textContent;
  child.parentNode.replaceChild(newChild, child);
};

const changeElement = (isElementSameType) => {
  // Diffing Algorithm Running to find the difference

  if (isElementSameType)
    updateContent();
  else
    updateElement();

};
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Imitating React</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="content"></button>
  <button id="element"></button>
  <div id="root"></div>
</body>

</html>



If you want to make sure that only the particular element is changing and not the whole tree, Inspect Element on that element and check the elements that blink when you click any of those buttons. Partial Rendering in browser

So what you're saying is, it IS possible to update only parts of the DOM using plain Javascript. Is that right?

Yes, it's possible using DOM manipulation and that's how React does it too. I have explained further by implementing React like mechanism in DOM rendering in the new Edit. Check out!

Perhaps the exact point which requires clarification may be this :
The difference between :
a) A regular web page
b) A web page in a SPA - single page application
As we know, a regular web page is essentially an HTML file optionally including JavaScript code for interactivity.
We also know, SPA is essentially an application in a Browser which shows web contents with respect to user interactions, it shows everything in the same single HTML page, and SPA does its work using JavaScript code alone, it cannot use anything other than JavaScript for this purpose since it runs in a Web browser. Therefore A web page in a SPA is the work of some JavaScript code.
From a user’s point of view, apparently both are the same. Still from a technical or run-time system point of view, both are different. Now if we figure out the run-time difference, it may be the answer to the question. The fundamental difference is the display or rendering logic in SPA. This rendering logic is not there in a regular web page.
This rendering logic should not be necessarily provided by a third party as it is in the case of a React application. This logic can be developed as part of the application code itself. And everything can be seen as monolithic code. However, when it comes to reusability or sharing the same rendering logic in multiple applications, it becomes natural to see that part of the code alone is separated as a library or a framework. However at runtime, it becomes part of the application, and runs as a single system.
So answering the question - So how does the code only update the parts of the DOM that need updating?
The answer is the runtime code knows it. It is a complete set of code, consisting of both - the application logic as well as rendering logic. It knows since it has the extra code or logic in it. This extra code is in JavaScript itself.
Now JSX is not a need of a run-time system, rather it is a need of a developmental system. JSX makes programming more and more declarative in nature. Therefore once the developmental phase is over, and the run-time system has been built, there is only JavaScript code - doing the intended job in Browsers. And it is delivered to Browser and it runs there as a SPA powered by JavaScript alone.
